# How to design multiple full-screen prototype cells using xcode's interface builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, collectionview

My app needs to horizontally scroll/page between different full-screen "views" or cells, where different views or cells have different layouts. The underlying model suggests that a collection view suits well, since the different pages are all inter-related in that they edit different items belonging to the same group. But I can't figure out how to design different full-screen prototype cells for a collection view using interface builder. Is this possible and if so how?

If it's not possible, please kindly recommend an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design the cells in xib files or in the storyboard. If you design in the storyboard, modify the item size to be full screen, then change the number of items to however many cells you want. You will be able to scroll between them in the collection view to add your subviews. Alternately, you can make each cell in its own xib file. In your collection view controller class, register each of the xibs with `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(SCREEN_SIZE.width, SCREEN_SIZE.height);
}
```

Comment: You should improve your answer . It should not only include code but a detailing explaining what you are doing.

Comment: please look at [answer]. Code-only answers aren't useful for the community